# Criptografia C# AES com MD5

Tags: c#, segurança, criptografia, md5, aes

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade onde preciso criptografar uma string com AES e Md5.

Quando eu faço a criptografia, retorna o resultado normal (eu acho), porém quando eu vou descriptografar, retorna o seguinte erro:

> **CryptographicException**: Os dados de entrada não são um bloco completo

O que poderia ser esse erro?

Códigos:

```
class Encryptor
{
    //MD5
    public static string GerarHashMd5(string input)
    {
        MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();
        // Converter a String para array de bytes, que é como a biblioteca trabalha.
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        // Cria-se um StringBuilder para recompôr a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop para formatar cada byte como uma String em hexadecimal
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }

    //AES
    static public byte[] encryptdata(byte[] bytearraytoencrypt, string key, string iv)
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider dataencrypt = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        //Block size : Gets or sets the block size, in bits, of the cryptographic operation.  
        dataencrypt.BlockSize = 128;
        //KeySize: Gets or sets the size, in bits, of the secret key  
        dataencrypt.KeySize = 128;
        //Key: Gets or sets the symmetric key that is used for encryption and decryption.  
        dataencrypt.Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        //IV : Gets or sets the initialization vector (IV) for the symmetric algorithm  
        dataencrypt.IV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
        //Padding: Gets or sets the padding mode used in the symmetric algorithm  
        dataencrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        //Mode: Gets or sets the mode for operation of the symmetric algorithm  
        dataencrypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        //Creates a symmetric AES encryptor object using the current key and initialization vector (IV).  
        ICryptoTransform crypto1 = dataencrypt.CreateEncryptor(dataencrypt.Key, dataencrypt.IV);
        //TransformFinalBlock is a special function for transforming the last block or a partial block in the stream.   
        //It returns a new array that contains the remaining transformed bytes. A new array is returned, because the amount of   
        //information returned at the end might be larger than a single block when padding is added.  
        byte[] encrypteddata = crypto1.TransformFinalBlock(bytearraytoencrypt, 0, bytearraytoencrypt.Length);
        crypto1.Dispose();
        //return the encrypted data  
        return encrypteddata;
    }

    //code to decrypt data
    static public byte[] decryptdata(byte[] bytearraytodecrypt, string key, string iv)
    {

        AesCryptoServiceProvider keydecrypt = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        keydecrypt.BlockSize = 128;
        keydecrypt.KeySize = 128;
        keydecrypt.Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        keydecrypt.IV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
        keydecrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        keydecrypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform crypto1 = keydecrypt.CreateDecryptor(keydecrypt.Key, keydecrypt.IV);

        byte[] returnbytearray = crypto1.TransformFinalBlock(bytearraytodecrypt, 0, bytearraytodecrypt.Length);
        crypto1.Dispose();
        return returnbytearray;
    }
}
```

Função de criptografar:

```
private void criptografar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string key;
    string text;
    string iv = "HR$2pIjHR$2pIj12"; // aleatório
    string keyMd5;

    key = Senha.Text;
    keyMd5 = Encryptor.GerarHashMd5(key);
    key = "";

    text = Entrada.Text;
    byte[] textArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text); // conversão pra encryptar
    byte[] encrypted = Encryptor.encryptdata(textArray, keyMd5, iv); // encryptador

    Saida.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted);
}
```

Função de descriptografar:

```
private void descriptografar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string key;
    string text;
    string iv = "HR$2pIjHR$2pIj12"; // aleatório
    string keyMd5;

    key = Senha.Text;
    keyMd5 = Encryptor.GerarHashMd5(key);
    key = "";

    text = Entrada.Text;
    byte[] textArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text); // conversão pra encryptar
    byte[] decrypted = Encryptor.decryptdata(textArray, keyMd5, iv); // decryptador

    Saida.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
}
```

E aqui é o resultado que gerou da criptografia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Atualização

O maior problema da sua abordagem é converter o *array* de `byte` para *string*. Normalizar os dados para uma *string* vai acabar fazendo com que alguns sejam perdidos.

Se realmente é necessário uma representação em *string* da senha, faça a conversão para Base64.

Eu ajustei o código pra funcionar corretamente.

```
class Program
{
    private const string IV = "HR$2pIjHR$2pIj12";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var senha = "123";
        var entrada = "teste22";

        var cripto = criptografar(senha, entrada);
        var cripto64 = Convert.ToBase64String(cripto);
        WriteLine($"Representação em string (em base64) da criptografia: {cripto64}");

        var decrip = descriptografar(senha, cripto);
        WriteLine($"Texto original (pelo byte[]): {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrip)}");

        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cripto64);
        var decBase64 = descriptografar(senha, bytes);
        WriteLine($"Texto original (string base64): {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decBase64)}");
    }

    static byte[] criptografar(string senha, string entrada)
    {
        string keyMd5 = Encryptor.GerarHashMd5(senha);
        return Encryptor.encryptdata(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(entrada), keyMd5, IV);
    }

    static byte[] descriptografar(string senha, byte[] criptografado)
    {
        string keyMd5 = Encryptor.GerarHashMd5(senha);                      
        return Encryptor.decryptdata(criptografado, keyMd5, IV);
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vc3y2k)</sup>

---

O problema é que pra fazer o processo inverso é preciso passar como primeiro parâmetro de `decryptData` o array de `bytes` do texto criptografado:

No código atual, você está passando o *array* com a *string* em texto normal, veja:

```
byte[] textArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text); // GetBytes da entrada
byte[] decrypted = Encryptor.decryptdata(textArray, keyMd5, iv); // Tenta fazer o processo
```

O código deveria ficar assim (dei uma encurtada pra não ficar ruim de ler)

```
static void descriptografar_Click(string senha, string entrada)
{
    string iv = "HR$2pIjHR$2pIj12"; // aleatório
    string keyMd5 = Encryptor.GerarHashMd5(senha);

    WriteLine($"Hash MD5: {keyMd5}");

    byte[] textArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(entrada); // GetBytes da entrada
    byte[] input = Encryptor.encryptdata(textArray, keyMd5, iv); // criptografa a entrada
    byte[] decrypted = Encryptor.decryptdata(input, keyMd5, iv); // fazer o processo

    WriteLine($"Saida.Text: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted)}");
}
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HU8ZwX)**</sup>